# Trouble importing a module that imports a module

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I'm having trouble with a python package that uses separate modules to structure code. The package itself is working, however when imported from another environment fails with a ModuleNotFound error.
Here's the structure:

```
Project-root
|
|--src/
|    __init__.py
|    module_a.py
|    module_b.py
|    module_c.py
|    module_d.py
|--tests
etc.
```

In module_a.py I have:

```
from module_a import function_a1,...
from module_b import function_b1,...
from module_c import function_c1,...
```

In module_c I import module_d like:

```
from module_d import function_d1,...
```

As mentioned above, executing module_a or module_c directly from the CLI work as expected, the unit tests I've created in the test directory also work (with the help of sys.path.insert), however if I create a new environment and import the package I get the following error:

```
>>> import module_a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<abs_path>/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/module_a.py", line 22, in <module>
    from module_c import function_c1, function_c2
  File /<abs_path>/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/module_c.py", line 9, in <module>
    import module_d
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_d'
>>>
```

I've exhausted all ideas how to overcome this, besides combining the code of modules c and d in one file, which I'd hate to do, or rethink the flow so that all modules are imported from module_a.
Any suggestions how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.
Update: It turned out to be a typing mistake in the name of module_d in setup.py. For whatever reason `python setup.py install` was failing silently or I wasn't reading the logs carefully.

Comment: `from .module_d import function_d1`

Comment: or use absolute imports: `from your_package.module_d import function_d1`

Comment: @Wups even if that works, it doesn't explain why a similar import in module_a works without the extra decoration.

Comment: Using `from .module_d import function_d1` throws  `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.  I can't understand the suggestion  to use `from your_package.module_d` but both `from Project-root.module_d` and `from src.module_d` are failing with i.e. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes down to understanding the basics of the **import system** and the **PYTHONPATH**.

When you try to import a module (`import module_a`), Python will search in order in every directory listed in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). If in one of them it finds a directory that matches the name (`module_a`)<sup>1</sup>, then it runs the `__init__.py` file is such exist. If it finds a file, it gets directly converted to a module.

When you get an [`ImportError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ImportError), it means that there is no directory in `sys.path` containing a file/directory with the name asked.

You said for your tests you did something like `sys.path.insert(0, "some/path/")`, but it is not a solution, just a broken fix.

What you should do is set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to contain the directory where your modules are located, `Project-root/src` in your case. That way, no need to ever use `sys.path.insert`, or fiddle with relative/absolute paths in import statements.

When you create your new environment, just set your environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to include `Project-root/src` and you are done. This is how installing regular Python modules (libraries) work : they are all put into a directory in `site-packages`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: this changed since old Python versions, it used to be required for the directory to contain an `__init__.py` file, see [PEP-420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although it doesn't explain why `import module_b` works but module_d raises the error, it helped me find my mistake (typo in setup.py).

Comment: @ddppddpp it depends on what you ask Python to do. From the project root, if you run `python src/module_b/something.py`, which does `import module_d`, it will search for `module_d` in the directories listed in the `PYTHONPATH`/`sys.path`, which includes `.` (the current directory, kindly added by Python), which is `Project-root`, but it will not find `module_d` which is in `Project-root/src`. What exactly do you do to run your `module_b` which fails to import `module_d` ?

Comment: In module_a I import module_c and execute function_c, then in module_c I import module_d and and execute funtion_d. I can execute module_a or module_c directly. All clear now, thx!

Comment: @ddppddpp then you can mark my answer as solving your question ;-)